# Java: Casting ParentClass and ChildClass (Downcast Runtime Error)

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion, downcast

```
public class InheritanceDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ParentClass p = new ParentClass();
        ChildClass c = new ChildClass();

        //Casting ChildClass to ParentClass
        ParentClass pc = new ChildClass();
        pc.parentClassMethod(); //Output: Parent Class Method (as expected)

        //Again Casting Parent Class to ChildClass explictly
        //Question 1 for this code
        ChildClass cp = (ChildClass) pc;
        cp.parentClassMethod(); //Output: Parent Class Method (unexpected)

        ChildClass cc1 = (ChildClass) new ParentClass();
        cc1.parentClassMethod(); //Compiles, but Run Time Error

        ChildClass cc2 = (ChildClass) p;
        cc2.parentClassMethod(); //Compiles, but Run Time Error

    }
}

class ParentClass {

    public void parentClassMethod(){
        System.out.println("Parent Class Method");
    }

}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

    public void ParentClassMethod(){
        System.out.println("Parent Class Method From Child Class");
    }

    public void ChildClassMethod(){
        System.out.println("Child Class Method");
    }

}
```

Question1:

Now, I have a method called `parentClassMethod` in both `ParentClass` and `ChildClass` classes(Overridden). When I cast the `ParentClass` to `ChildClass` and then call the parentClassMethod, why is it executing the `ParentClass` method instead of the method from `ChildClass` if cp is refering to `ChildClass`?

Question2:

(i) `ChildClass cp = (ChildClass) pc;`

(ii) `ChildClass cc1 = (ChildClass) new ParentClass();`
(iii) `ChildClass cc2 = (ChildClass) p;`

If (i) is working fine, why not (ii) or (iii)?

Because I am casting from `ParentClass` to `ChildClass` in both the cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I have a method called parentClassMethod in both ParentClass and ChildClass classes(Overridden).

No you don't.  You have a method named `parentClassMethod` in `ParentClass` and a method named `ParentClassMethod` in `ChildClass`.  Since all Java identifiers are case-sensitive, there is no association between the two.  `ParentClassMethod` does not override `parentClassMethod` from `ParentClass`.

> If (i) is working fine, why not (ii) or (iii)?

In (ii) and (iii) you are trying to cast an instance of `ParentClass` to an instance of `ChildClass`. That is not allowed, as a `ChildClass` is-not-a `ParentClass`, any more than an `Object` is a `String`.

In (i) you are trying to cast an instance of `ChildClass` (stored in a reference declared as `ParentClass`) to a `ChildClass`, which is allowed.

When casting, it's the runtime type that counts (in other words, what `T` is used in `new T()`).

Comment: This is why you should ***ALWAYS*** use the `@Override` annotation.  If you put it on `ChildClass#ParentClassMethod()` you would get an error telling you, in effect (best Mandy Patinkin/Iñigo Montoya Princess Bride accent) "I do not think that method overrides what you think it overrides".

Comment: Thanks Mark, for the reply. It was my mistake in the program where I typed ParentClassMethod instead of parentClassMethod. Now, I can see the difference. It works!!!

Comment: When I cast a ParentClass object to a ChildClass object then I can access the methods in both ParentClass and ChildClass. But how is it allowed to access the methods when I cast a ChildClass object to ParentClass Object? i.e. I need to be allowed to only access methods inside ParentClass right? Please make this clear? Thank you.

Comment: *When I cast a ParentClass object to a ChildClass object then I can access the methods in both ParentClass and ChildClass.* Casting an instance of `ParentClass` to `ChildClass` will always fail, so what methods it allows you to use is irrelevant.  If you mean you had a `ChildClass` in a *variable* declared as `ParentClass`, and you casted that *variable* to `ChildClass`, then that is correct.  If you put a `ChildClass` in a `ParentClass`-typed variable, you can only see the methods from `ParentClass`, but at runtime the most specific method (`ChildClass`) will still be called.

Answer (score 0):

Lets go back to jdk 1.4 when generics were not there.

```
  Vector test = new Vector();
   test.add("java");
```

Now while retrieving what you do:

```
String str = (String) test.get(0);
```

So string was initially stored as an object inside vector and then you downcasted it to String and it went fine.

But if you try following, it wont work:

```
String str = (Object) new Object();
```

So you can see that in first case the it was of String but reference was of Object [inside vector], in this scenario you can downcast and it will work.

To answer your first question java is case sensitive and case of your method names donot match.